# How to use audio tag in jsp

Tags: html, jsp, html5-audio

I want to play mp3 or ogg files in a jsp page with the html5 audio tag.
When I use the audio tag in a plain html page everything works but when I try to use it in a jsp page nothing seems to work.

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%--<%@page contentType="audio/mpeg3" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>--%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!--        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">-->
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    <br>
    <audio controls="controls">  
        <source src="/home/stelios/html5/recit.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
        Your browser does not support the audio tag.
    </audio> 
</body>
</html>
```

I have also tried to set the contentType to audio/mpeg3 but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URL

```
http://localhost:8080/home/stelios/html5/recit.mp3
```

probably doesn't exist (assuming your web container runs on port 8080 on your own machine).

The `src` attribute of the `audio` tag is an URL, not a file path on the client or server machine.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically, the browser is designed to detect the MIME type of the embedded file.
Try to use embed tag instead of source tag.
The embed tag is used to include the audio file in jsp.

For example:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>

<html>
<head><title>Choose Your Tunes</title></head>
<body>

<h2>Thanks for listining to the song:</h2>

<embed src="ConstantCraving.mp3" width="240" height="160">
</embed>

</body>
</html>
```

Its just a sample code and is not tested.

The other problem may be the unavailability of the source file.

If you could specify the error, it would be eaiser to help

Comment: Note: Some older version of browser doesnot completely suppport HTML5